# std::string trouble comparing multibyte symbols like € º or ª

Tags: c++, string, comparison

My problem is that I have a `std::string` which contains numbers and one of the following characters: %, $, €, º or ª.  I have to store the number and the symbol separately in a `std::list`.

The problem is that the symbols `€`, `º` and `ª` have multibyte encodings and I can't make a direct comparison with the operator `==`, so I'm looking for any tip or good practices for comparing these multibyte characters.

Comment: Yes I mixed up 'multivaluated' and 'multibyte. Thanks for the quick repli.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably refer to these symbols being *multibyte* in your current encoding, probably UTF-8.

If that's the case, the easiest solution is to consider them, not chars but small strings, as in C++ a `char` is not actually a *character* but a *byte*.

So, to find wheter your string has a `€` in it:

```
std::string x = "I have 100.00 €".
std::string::size_type pos = x.find("€");
```

Note that the `"€"` uses double quotes, not single quotes, as it is a small string, not a char.

The rest of the algorithms are not so different than with single chars. The only other difference I can think of is that `strlen("€") > 1`.

Comment: Yes, that was what I tried to explain, thank you for the understanding and the quick answer, worked great for me.